# ClassNotFoundException in cucumber framework

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, cucumber-java, maven-exec-plugin

I am using Cucumber framework for mobile app testing. In pom.xml, I have given this below plugin to run TestClass.java - which has code for uploading the latest APK version of the app. Main method is present inside this TestClass. I need this to run before the actual test execution. So I have used exec plugin. I'm getting this error if I am running with pom.xml --> mvn clean test. ClassNotFoundExpection is always thrown with pom.xml, but the individual class runs perfectly.

pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
       <executions>
    <execution>
            <id>installAPK</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
        <mainClass>org.com.package1.TestClass</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Console error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.com.package1.TestClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:246)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I also tried changing the phase after test-compile. Still i am getting the same error. Someone pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [exec-maven-plugin documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html), the default dependency scope for the execution is `runtime`. Please change it to `test` with the following configuration if the `TestClass` is part of the test sources.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    ...
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    ...
    <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Just a query. If I am having the TestClass at src/main/java without adding this <classpathScope> will this work?

Comment: Yes, default dependency scope for the execution is `runtime`, which includes main classes and compile/runtime dependencies.